# Cytoscape.js Yfiles orthogonal edges

Tags: cytoscape.js, yfiles

Can we use Yfiles with cytoscape.js to render orthogonal edges. My layout is a preset layout of compound nodes. I want the child nodes of the compound node to connect via orthogonal edges to other nodes.

Comment: Can you provide an example (image, fiddle, ...) of what you want ?

Comment: Hi @Deeps, please refer to [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question accordingly, thank you:)

Comment: Not able to add a image here. But I have nodes which contains nodes inside. I give fixed positions to parent nodes and the child nodes as well, in a sort of a grid layout. The connections through each of these nodes is with a straight lines which would cross over the nodes which come on the way. So, I would want the edges to be like orthogonal edges while avoiding cross-over other nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I actually don't know what you mean with "yfiles with cytoscape.js". But if you want to do orthogonal edges with cytoscape.js maybe have a look [here](http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/edge-line).
If this doesn't answer your question maybe give some example.